# PrimeFaces Rich Text editor convert into normal inputTextArea

Tags: primefaces

I want to ask that sometimes what happen that if I use PrimeFaces Rich Text Editor then instead of showing Rich Text Editor, it shows normal inputTextArea. I want to know what can be the reasons that Rich Text Editor is not shown. Why it shows normal text Area instead of Rich Text Area?  My Javascript is also enabled. Please tell me the reasons.

Thanks

Edit:

---

Here is my code

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>

        <ui:composition template="./WEB-INF/templates/layout.xhtml">
            <ui:define name="title">Add City Images</ui:define>
            <ui:define name="content">

            <h:form id="cityDetailForm" prependId="false" >

                <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true" life="2000"> </p:growl>

                <p:panel id="panel1"
                         style="border-color: #000000;width: 954px;position: absolute;left: 150px;height: 450px;-moz-border-radius: 11px; -webkit-border-radius: 11px; border-radius: 11px; behavior: url(../PIE/PIE.htc)">

                    <strong Class="MainHeader">
                        <p:spacer width="10"/> City Detail
                    </strong>

                    <h:panelGrid columns="5"
                                 border=""
                                 width="20%"
                                 style="position: absolute; top: 50px;"
                                 columnClasses="asteriskColumns, nameColumns" >

                        <h:outputText value="*" />
                        <h:outputText value="Map: " />
                        <p:fileUpload id="cityMap"
                                      description="Image"
                                      update="city messages"
                                      allowTypes="*.jpg;*.png;*.gif;*.jpeg;"
                                      auto="true"
                                      fileUploadListener="#{cityDetail.imageUpload}" >

                        </p:fileUpload>

                        <p:graphicImage id="city"
                                        value="#{cityDetail.imagePath}"
                                        width="80"
                                        height="50"
                                        cache="false">

                            <f:event type="preRenderComponent" listener="#{cityDetail.putImage}" />

                        </p:graphicImage>

                        <h:commandLink value="remove"
                                       title="Remove Picture"
                                       style="color: #0d5b7f;text-decoration: underline"
                                       onclick="if (! confirm('Are you sure, you want to remove picture?') ) { return false;}; return true; ">

                            <f:ajax event="click"
                                    render="city"
                                    listener="#{cityDetail.removeImage}"/>

                         </h:commandLink>

                         .....

                    </h:panelGrid>

                    <h:panelGrid columns="1"
                                 border=""
                                 width="60%"
                                 style="position: absolute; top: 40px;left: 350px;height: 410px ">

                        <p:editor value="#{cityDetail.CKeditorValue}" widgetVar="editor" width="600"/>

                    </h:panelGrid>

                    <h:commandButton id="preview"
                                     value="Preview"
                                     action="#{cityDetail.preview}"
                                     style="position: absolute; top: 470px; left: 400px"
                                     styleClass="ButtonStyle" />

                    <h:commandButton id="save"
                                     value="Save"
                                     actionListener="#{cityDetail.sendImagesToDatabase}"
                                     action="#{cityDetail.save}"
                                     style="position: absolute; top: 470px; left: 475px;"
                                     styleClass="ButtonStyle">

                    </h:commandButton>

                    <h:commandButton id="cancel"
                                     value="Cancel"
                                     action="#{cityDetail.cancel}"
                                     style="position: absolute; top: 470px; left: 550px;"
                                     styleClass="ButtonStyle" />
                      <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.modaldialog1.css"/>
            <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
            <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.modaldialog.js"></script>
            <h:commandButton id="YesAfterSaveBtn" onclick="$(dialogmask).hide();$(dialog).hide()"  action="#{cityDetail.goBack}"  style="background-color: #e6eff6;border: #e6eff6"></h:commandButton>
            <h:outputText value="#{cityDetail.errorScript}" escape="false"/>

                </p:panel>
            </h:form>
        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
</h:body>
```

[image]

You can see that i am using Prime Faces editor, but it is showing me inputTextArea. Although i didn't try the solution but this is what i asked for.

thanks

Comment: are you referring to primefaces `Editor` component? Sometimes it shows the editor and other times a simple textArea?

Comment: @spauny Yes exactly, why it happens?

Comment: I'm using the editor for a long time now, but I have never encountered this problem... could you show an image and some code to prove what you're saying?

Comment: do you see any java scripts error while having this issues? does it happen on particular browsers only?

Comment: @spauny i edited my code. You can see the code as well as image. Thanks

Comment: @Daniel no, no java-script errors. I checked it on FireaFox and IE8. Both are showing the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

set `<f:view contentType="text/html"/>`

as mentioned in the following thread of primefaces forum [p:editor like h:inputTextArea](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6831)

Comment: put it after the  <h:body> and close it before the </h:body> , in other words wrap the  <ui:composition with the f:view

Comment: no it's not working. I read that ui:composition discard all the tags outside it. I think i have to put it in my layout.xhtml page

Comment: ok, haven't tried this myself but the solution according to primefaces forum should be with the <f:view contentType="text/html"/>

Comment: I myself wrap with the f:view the entire code right after the html tag

Comment: This was happening because of the Jquery conflicts. Thanks